# How to improve quality of edge over support

Tags: pla, creality-cr-10, support-structures, prusaslicer

I am having trouble with my print here, specifically with the part laying on the green support:

[image: Print preview of a 3D model in PrusaSlicer]

It seems the edge running on the supports does not stick to it and it wants to curl upwards :

[image: Photo of a printed model curling upwards on the buildplate]

I have reduced layer height to 0.1 mm and support Z distance to 0.05 mm. I am using the tight support setting in prusa slicer. The perimeter is printed at 35 mm/s and the temperatures are 200 °C and 73 °C for the bed to print PLA+.

Here is what I would like to get close to side by side with the current result. The good one is printed upside down and takes me 23h to print instead of 12h, so I would like to find a good fix for this ;)

[image: Photo of the same printed model with one upside down above the other]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like inadequate cooling. If this is PLA, it's probably a matter of PLA this close to a hot bed being unable to cool enough not to still be soft - the heat from the bed will continually heat the part, and it doesn't take much heat to keep it soft. If you're using a bed temperature of 60°C (common recoommendation for PLA) this is hopelessly too hot for any small parts with overhangs to print close to the bed. Try reducing it or printing with a completely cold bed using a non-heat-based method for adhesion. Some good ones are a textured surface like painter's tape/"blue tape", especially roughed up with light sanding, or an adhesive aid like glue stick or hair spray.

Comment: will give it a try. Thank you!